# How to set y axis range instead of every value of the list on python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm struggling about how can i set a range numbers on Y axis to get rid of every value, also i'm trying to remove the line and just set the '+' marks, i've tried everything: ylim, axis... Thanks in advance

[image: wtf]

CODE:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100)+1)  # i'm trying to fix my problem with this
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
#plt.plot(blabla['data0'], marker='+', color='mediumaquamarine', label=2018)
#plt.plot(blabla['data11'], marker='+', color='r', label=2017)
plt.plot(blabla["gdsgweg"], blabla["wefwef"], marker='+', color='red', label=2017)
plt.plot(blabla["wefwfe"], blabla["wefwf"], marker='+', color='mediumaquamarine', label=2018)
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))  # i'm trying to fix my problem with this
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code?

Comment: You forgot to convert your data to numbers.

Comment: They are numbers already, if not couldn't represent it on a plot...

Comment: How could i remove all the data from y axis and set from 0 to 1000? because ylim didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly converting your y-values to numbers (either float or int). In your code you could try for example:

```
blabla["wefwef"] = pd.to_numeric(blabla["wefwef"], errors='coerce')
blabla["wefwf"] = pd.to_numeric(blabla["wefwf"], errors='coerce')

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100)+1)  # i'm trying to fix my problem with this
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(blabla["gdsgweg"], blabla["wefwef"], marker='+', color='red', label=2017)
plt.plot(blabla["wefwfe"], blabla["wefwf"], marker='+', color='mediumaquamarine', label=2018)
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(prune='lower'))  # i'm trying to fix my problem with this
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok friend, i know it can be the problem because im getting: ValueError: could not convert string to float: NA but before i did blabla['Price'] = blabla['Price'].fillna(0) cannot understand why the error...

Comment: try the ```pd.to_numeric()``` method with the  ```errors='coerce'``` argument to force the strings to ```nan``` values

Comment: ok my friend, i fixed it you were right, i was using "FILLNA" method but the problem is the data was a string NA and it didnt change after the method, since now i will be carefully about the data im dealing with, didnt expect about it, i did a replace casting to str and then on a plot using the method "ASTYPE(FLOAT)"